# Old anime with a red-haired protagonist who fights demons

Tags: identification-request

I've been trying to find this anime for years, the last time I saw it was in 2002 when I was 4. I remember it was on a VHS that we rented.

It was about a red-haired boy, who I believe fought demons. He would transform in the style of Yugi Muto into a bigger and older-looking self when fighting those demons.

I can only remember one episode where he fought a super fast wolf-looking demon that was actually a young marathon runner possessed by some king of a golden eye if I remember correctly. Anyway, the red-haired boy protagonist would eat that eye when he defeats his opponent and they would return to normal.

That's about all I can remember, and I would appreciate all the info I can get, thanks.

Comment: welcome to A&M SE, please try to add the specific date, we don't know what date was it when you were 4.

Comment: We don't know how old you are. "When I was 4" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I think you are talking about this character [Kurama](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama).

As you will he has red-hair and an older look as you said.
He is fighting demons.
And also it's very old anime (1992)

Comment: Kurama never fought a super fast wolf-looking demon that was actually a young marathon runner.

Comment: You can always create a new answer or feel free to edit my answer  @HashiramaSenju :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's [Zenki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenki)

[image]

> Zenki appears to be a child who transforms into his true and powerful demon form. In the early episodes, Chiaki needed to use the bracelet to transform Zenki into his true form. In the final episode, however, Zenki's anger allows him to transform into his true self. With the help of the bracelet and Goki, another powerful demon spirit, Chiaki is able to transform Zenki into a super powerful demon spirit. The bracelet is no longer necessary when Chiaki attains her full powers in the final episode of the series. Zenki likes to eat the Karuma Seeds for they are delicious.